# chartArea position properties don't work in vba Excel 2013

Tags: vba, excel

I'm noob in vba (Excel macros). I need to add somes charts automatically in the same WorkSheet. This is my code:

```
Sub runChart()
    Dim xchart As Chart
    Dim nameSheet As String
    nameSheet = ActiveSheet.Name
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim firstIndex As Integer
    Dim firstValue As Integer
    Dim actualValue As Integer
    Dim actualIndex As Integer
    Dim rChart1 As Range
    Dim rChart2 As Range
    MsgBox nameSheet
    firstIndex = 2
    actualIndex = 2
    firstValue = Cells(2, 1)
    actualValue = Cells(2, 1)
    Do
       Do
           actualIndex = actualIndex + 1
           actualValue = Sheets(nameSheet).Cells(actualIndex, 1)
       Loop Until firstValue <> actualValue

       Set rChart1 = Range(Sheets(nameSheet).Cells(firstIndex, "E"),      Sheets(nameSheet).Cells(actualIndex - 1, "E"))
       Set rChart1 = Union(rChart1, Range(Sheets(nameSheet).Cells(firstIndex, "J"), Sheets(nameSheet).Cells(actualIndex - 1, "J")))
       Dim nameChart As String
       nameChart = CStr(Sheets(nameSheet).Cells(firstIndex, 5)) & " - " & Sheets(nameSheet).Cells(actualIndex, 5) & " " & CStr(Sheets(nameSheet).Cells(firstIndex, 1))
       Set xchart = Charts.Add
       With xchart
            .Name = nameChart
            .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
            .SetSourceData rChart1
            .Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:=nameSheet

             'position and size chart
            .ChartArea.Top = 10 'this position is a example
            .ChartArea.Left = 1700 'this position is a example
            .ChartArea.Height = 400 'this size is a example
            .ChartArea.Width = 750 'this size is a example
        End With

        firstValue = Sheets(nameSheet).Cells(actualIndex, 1)
        firstIndex = actualIndex

     Loop Until (Sheets(nameSheet).Cells(actualIndex, 1) = vbNullString)
End Sub
```

So, my problem happens is in .ChartArea.left = 1700. The program says :

> The specified dimension is not valid for the current chart type

anyone has any idea what 's happening? Thanks for your time :)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with the positioning? Do you want to move the entire chart or the chart area within the chart object? I believe code is doing the latter and your chart may be too small. Maybe this will be of help: [Resizing and Moving Excel Charts with VBA](http://peltiertech.com/Excel/ChartsHowTo/ResizeAndMoveAChart.html)

Answer (score 0):

The ChartArea is the overall rectangle containing the chart within its parent ChartObject (the shape that contains the embedded chart). The position and size of the ChartArea are read only. But that's okay, you want to position and resize the ChartObject, which is the chart's .Parent.

```
   With xchart
        'position and size chart
        .Parent.Top = 10 'this position is a example
        .Parent.Left = 1700 'this position is a example
        .Parent.Height = 400 'this size is a example
        .Parent.Width = 750 'this size is a example
    End With
```